# rfc2047 multiple encoded-word in email subject

Tags: oracle, email

I need to send an email with the Subject containing cyrillic letters. But my recipients sometimes receive incorrect letters due to some problems with mail server and/or client. I always send emails in `windows-1251` encoding, but sometimes a mail client shows letter's Subject and Sender in another encoding (`KOI-8R`) and our users can't understand the message.
I tried to use an encoded-word tag as described in RFC 2047 Standard. For example, my Subject field in the email now looks like:

```
Subject: =?WINDOWS-1251?B?wiDt5eTw4PUg8vPt5PD7IOL75PD7IOIg4+Xy8OD1IPL78P/yIOIg4uXk8OAg/+Tw?=
=?WINDOWS-1251?B?4CDq5eTw4C4gwvvw4uDiIPEg4vvk8Psg4iDy8+3k8OUg4+Xy?=
=?WINDOWS-1251?B?8PssIOL78vDzIOL75PDu6SD/5PDgIOrl5PDgLCDi+/Lw8yDj?=
=?WINDOWS-1251?B?5fLw7ukg4vvk8OUg7O7w5PMsIP/k8OAg4iDi5eTw4Cwg4vvk?=
=?WINDOWS-1251?B?8PMg4iDy8+3k8PMu?=
```

These lines was generated by Oracle function `UTL_ENCODE.MIMEHEADER_ENCODE`.

All mail clients (Lotus Notes, gmail.com) show only the first line of such email subject (only first 48 symbols).
What is the problem with my mail subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you do not fold correctly, according to RFC 2822. To make a multi line field in the header each line has to start with a white space.

What you need to do is:

```
replace(UTL_ENCODE.MIMEHEADER_ENCODE(subject, 'UTF8', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64), UTL_TCP.CRLF, UTL_TCP.CRLF || ' ')
```

This should solve your problem.